# Postgres DB entry: Write by one user, read by another?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

If I have a DB model and it has the fields A,B,C,D and E; what can I expect to happen if a mobile client accesses the model to read the value of an entry for the Field "D", and at the same time a server updates Field "E" **of the same entry/record** , what can I expect to happen ? Will both writes and reads occur without an issue ?

Sorry if I haven't used the correct terminology.

Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes (your read and write will occur without "issue" (i.e.there should not be an errors). However, the expected behaviors very much depends on your [locking strategy](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) and [isolation levels](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html). The default isolation level in postgres the default isolation level for your select is *Read Committed*...which means:"the SELECT query sees a snapshot of the database as of the instant the query begins to run".

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal situation where it is not a standalone server and running multiple sessions. In postgreSQL this can be taken care of by having a check in the following

- [SERIALIZABLE transactions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Serializable)
- [Row level locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html)
- optimistic locking

For reference: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html